# Remote Directory Listing Python WSGI

Tags: python, linux, list, wsgi, dir

I'm currently an Intern in a IT service and I've been asked to build a web based app using Python that will run on a Linux environment. This web app has to be WSGI-compliant and I cannot use any framework.

My issue currently is that I want to have a variable set as a list of files in the said directory. Therefore I can then proceed to list those files by printing a table having each row being a file.

I am aware of os.listdir() but can't find a way to use it on a remote server (which is supposed not to be the case considering what google searches showed me...).

I tried an os.system(ssh root@someip:/path/to/dir/) but as python doc states, I cant get the output I want as it returns some integers...

Below is a piece of my script.

```
#ip is = to the ip of the server I want to list.

ip = 192..............

directory = "/var/lib/libvirt/images/"

command = "ssh root@"+ip+" ls "+directory

dirs = os.system(command)


files = ""
table_open = "<table>"
table_close = "</table>"
table_title_open = "<th>Server: "
table_title_close = "</th>"
tr_open = "<tr>"
tr_close = "</tr>"
td_open = "<td>"
td_close = "</td>"
input_open = "<input type='checkbox' name='choice' value='"
input_close = "'>"

#If i don't put dirs in brackets it raises an error (dirs not being iterable)
for file in [dirs]:

    files = files + tr_open+td_open+file+td_close+td_open+input_open+file+input_close+td_close+tr_close

table = table_open+table_title_open+str(num_server)+table_title_close+files+table_close
```

I've tried this with a local directory (with os.listdir) and it works perfectly. I am having troubles only with remote directory listing...

I do hope that my question is crystal clear, if not I'll do my best to be more accurate.

Thanks in advance,
-Karink.

Comment: check the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) it allows you to get output

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), here is an example:

```
import subprocess
ls = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','user@xx.xx.xx.xx', 'ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err =  ls.communicate()
print out
print err
```

Comment: Hello again, had few issues with SSH Keys but everything is working now so I just wanted to thank you for your help. Have a nice day ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use pysftp
first install it using **pip install pysftp** then the below code can list the files on remote linux machine from windows as well

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

with pysftp.Connection('ipLinuxmachine', username='username', password='passwd',cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    out=sftp.execute('cd path of directory ; ls')
    print out
```